# Problema al Guardar/Abrir imagen Android/Mysql/Php

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio

espero esten bien y me puedan ayudar. Básicamente es que no puedo visualizar la imagen que guardo en mi server mysql en el navegador. Mis códigos son estos:
Android Studio

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
ConnectivityManager connMgr =(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
url = "http://" + ip + "/envioFoto.php";
parametros = "datos="+  encodedImage ;
new EnviaDatos().execute(url);
```

Php guarda:

```
<?php
$imagen=$_POST["datos"];
$actualiza="UPDATE tabla SET Foto='". $imagen ."' WHERE id=1";
mysqli_query($conecta,$actualiza);  
mysqli_close($conecta);
echo "ok" ;?>
```

En la BD lo guardo como varchar LONGBLOB latin1_swedish_ci

html muestra:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$quer="SELECT foto FROM tabla WHERE id='1'";
$sql3=$conecta->query($quer);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($sql3);
while($datos = $sql3->fetch_array()){
$imagen=$datos[0];
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($imagen) .' "/>';
} mysqli_close($conn);?>
</body>
</html>
```

> Y todo esto termina enque me muestra el icono de imagen rota. Veo que el array guardado en la base de datos llega, pero no lo puede traducir.

SABEN QUE PUEDE SER?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Cual es la url que tiene la imagen? , si se ve rota es que es incorrecta la ruta que agregas a el html.

Comment: Hola, gracia por responder. Hice la siguiente prueba: Saque una foto y la guarde en el telefono, mientras enviaba el array de la misma al server. Luego levante la foto una página que codifica en base 64 y lo pegué en el código <img>. La foto se ve perfectamente.... Hice lo mismo con el array guardado en mysql y la foto no se vé. Entre ellos no se parecen en nada. Creo que el problema debe estar en como guardo el array en android studio o en un problema de formatos entre android y mysql. Habrá alguna solución o prueba para hacer?

Comment: El array guardado comienza asi: aVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQUFBTlNVaEVVZ0FBQU1FQUFBRUNDQUlBQUFESUt5U

El transformado en la web así: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8LCwk
En el guardado en la base de datos no hay espacios y en el convertido por página si. Otra de las diferencias.